# How we can show toggle on page for navigation drawer in android

Tags: android

How we can create navigation drawer according to the image below:

[image]

If anybody have idea or example please share me.

Comment: use the template **Navigation Drawer Activity**  in android studio it is the perfect example for  you

Answer (score 0):

To replace the drawer indicator icon with your own drawable(non animated) using the v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle, you can do the following:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),   R.drawable.your_custom_icon, getActivity().getTheme());

mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
 mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
          mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     } else {
         mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the template [Navigation Drawer Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) in android studio it is the perfect example for you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @NKmewara says, you can use Navigation Drawer by creating a project with **Navigation Drawer Activity** template in Android Studio.

You can also visit [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Or a simpler ways, you can use [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) by which you only need to add:

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

then just add the following line to your activity:

```
new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();
```

Voila!